# Comparing ptrdiff_t with size_t

Tags: c, integer, language-lawyer, conversion-rank

I have a question about the following simple comparison:

```
#define BUF_SIZE //maybe large

static char buf[BUF_SIZE];

static char *limit; // some pointer to an element of buf array

void foo(){
    if(limit - buf <= sizeof buf){  //<---- This comparison
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Here we are comparing `ptrdiff_t` (on the left) which is signed and `size_t` (on the right) which is unsigned. The Standard provides the following explanation

`6.5.8/3`:

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed.

`6.3.1.8/1` gives us 3 possibilities:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

We don't know the conversion rank of `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t`. Moreover there is no in general a corresponding unsigned type for `ptrdiff_t` (unlike, say `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`).

**QUESTION**: Suppose that the conversion rank of `ptrdiff_t` is strictly greater than of `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` cannot represent all the values of `size_t`. What will happen when performing comparison between `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` providing that there is no corresponding unsigned integer type for `ptrdiff_t`. Is such an implementation even allowed?

Comment: Why is 6.2.5/6 not applicable? It clearly says that there must be an unsigned type corresponding to `ptrdiff_t`. We don't know what its name is, but it must exist.

Comment: @rici the clause defines the corresponding unsigned type using the keyword `unsigned`. But according to 6.7.2/2 `unsigned ptrdiff_t` is not a valid type specifier.

Comment: St.Antario: No. If `ptrdiff_t` is a type alias, the corresponding unsigned type is the corresponding unsigned type of the type `ptrdiff_t` is an alias of.  Type aliases are not different types; they are different names for the same type. That's why I said we don't know the name of the corresponding unsigned type. The fact that we don't know how to declare it does not mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: In fact, `ptrdiff_t` might be an alias of an extended integer type, whose name is in the part of the namespace reserved for the implementation. But it still will have a corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: @rici But the Standard does not specify `ptrdiff_t` to be exactly a type alias of a standard integer type. In case it is then yes, there is a corresponding unsigned type. Otherwise it is not specified.

Comment: Yes, it does. It says that `ptrdiff_t` is a "signed integer type", which is a phrase precisely defined by the standard. (6.5.6/9). (Definition at 6.2.5/4: "The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types."

Comment: @rici As you said an Impelemtation can define `ptrdiff_t` to be an alias of an extended integer type. From 6.5.2/6 _For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword unsigned)_. What is the reason for _designated with the keyword unsigned_ then? 6.7.2/2 does not allow `unsigned` type specifier with anything but standard integer types.

Comment: if taken literally, that would mean you couldn't declare a variable of that type. But an implementation is actually free to implement any extension it likes, at least as long as the extended names are in the extension namespace (eg. `_Ptrdiff`, with corresponding type `unsigned _Ptrdiff`). But I repeat, even if you cannot name the unsigned type, *it exists*. The existence of a type is not contingent on it having a name.

Comment: After having this discussion, I think 6.7.2/2 needs a footnote, at least. But I think the intent is clear.

Comment: @rici If the wording regarding `unsigned` keyword means that we cannot declare a variable of that type then I think it is kind of redundant. If the Standard does not specify a corresponding unsigned type then we cannot declare a variable of that type anyway because there is no type specifier. We have `intptr_t` `uintptr_t` specified explicitly and the only `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: The various idiosyncracies of `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` have been discussed extensively over a span of more than two decades. Here, on mailing lists, on blogs, and most importantly in committee submissions. I don't think there's a high likelihood that another discussion will reveal anything new. If you are interested in implementations with extended integer types, you can certainly find them. I don't know if there is yet a consensus about the base names of such types; my sense is that type aliases are common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ptrdiff_t` is of greater rank than `size_t`and can represent all positive values of `size_t`.  `limit - buf <= sizeof buf` poses no problems then.  The compare is done as `ptrdiff_t`.

Else `ptrdiff_t` may not represent all positive values of `size_t` and then the *subtraction*  `limit - buf` may be UB per below, so the compare is [moot](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xewlks).

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>   The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>   ...
>   The result of subtracting two pointers is not representable in an object of type `ptrdiff_t` (6.5.6).

---

> Is such an implementation even allowed?  (conversion rank of `ptrdiff_t` is strictly greater than of `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` cannot represent all the values of `size_t`)

Yes may be allowed as `ptrdiff_t` as `long` and `size_t` as `unsigned`.  Both 32-bit.  But perhaps not wise.

---

Note: C17 § 7.19 4 has

**Recommended practice**
The types used for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` should not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of `signed long int` unless the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

Not that this applies a lot here - just a note.

Comment: _Yes may be allowed as ptrdiff_t as long and size_t as unsigned._ In this case there is a corresponding unsigned integer type for `ptrdiff_t`. The Standard does not specify that `ptrdiff_t` should be a `typedef`. In case `ptrdiff_t` has the same representation as `long` but without a corresponding unsigned integer type will we get UB when doing such comparison?

Comment: @St.Antario This answer does not rely on `ptrdiff_t` having a corresponding _unsigned_ type. In the first case,  `limit - buf <= sizeof buf` is all done as  `ptrdiff_t`.  In the next case, `limit - buf` is UB with large `limit`.